# Running Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) and failing to install GIT

Tags: apt, git

Attempting to install GIT using apt-get and it's failing.

All of the web searches turn up different commands none seem to work.

Output of the install command

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates git curl gnupg -y

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

curl is already the newest version (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.4).

gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1).

gnupg set to manually installed.

ca-certificates is already the newest version (20211016).

ca-certificates set to manually installed.

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have

requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable

distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:



The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note this is running in VirtualBox but I don't believe that should impact the outcome?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try to just install liberror-perl?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

First try to enable the multiverse repo: there should be a `Software & Updates` app in your app menu that has a tab called Ubuntu Software. Open it, and check if the multiverse and restricted options are checked. It should prompt you for your password when you modify them. After you're done, close the window and do `sudo bash -c 'dpkg --configure -a && apt update && apt upgrade'`. And with that finished try and install git again, it should work.